# Find childrenparent elements

Tags: javascript

How to find the maximum number of child element using in JavaScript ?

> ```
> <div>
>   <div>
>     <div>
>      <div></div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
>
> <div>
>   <div>
>  </div>
> </div> 
>
> <div>
>   <div>
>     <div>
>       <div>
>         <div></div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer maximum element: 4

Comment: the question is unclear.  Did you want the maximum depth of the DOM?

Comment: get all the div elements using dokument.getElementsByTagName.But then how to walk through each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id = "a">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
         <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
     </div>
    </div> 

    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getMaxChildrenCount(element) {
    var Max = { value: 0, i: -1 };

    (function getMaxChildren(element, Max) {
        var Childred = element.childNodes;
        Max.i++;
        for(var i = 0; i < Childred.length; i++) {
            getMaxChildren(Childred[i], Max);
        }
        Max.i--;
        if(Max.i > Max.value) Max.value = Max.i;
    })(element, Max);

    return Max.value;
}

console.log( getMaxChildrenCount(document.getElementById('a')) );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay may be it would helpful:

```
    <div class="bla">
      <div>
        <div>
         <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bla">
      <div>
     </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="bla">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

$('.bla').each(function(){
 var count = $(this).find('*').length;
})
```

hope u can continue)

**UPD:**

```
var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('bla');
for(var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++){
    var count = elm[i].getElementsByTagName('*').length;
}
```

Comment: There's a dot missing in `$('bla')`.

Comment: And if you do not give the id and class member, you can count? Then perhaps you need to use childNodes right?

Comment: U'll need to start from some point, even <body>, but yes, from first step childNodes can do the things.